# In the x86 (SYSV) calling convention, are function arguments zero-extended?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, calling-convention

In the x86 SYSV (linux) calling convention, the first 6 arguments are passed in 64-bit registers.  If these arguments are less than 64-bits, is the top of those registers guaranteed to be zeroed, or is it undefined?  Is it different for 32-bit arguments and smaller arguments?

Comment: The linked duplicate is a different question, but the answer to it very thoroughly answers this question as well.  Is it still a duplicate?

Comment: It is close enough as a duplicate. It really is about whether the upper bits are guaranteed to be zero. The answer gives a detailed response that effectively boils down to the upper bits of the general purpose registers should be assumed to have garbage except with a `bool` type where bit 0 is the truth value and the upper 7 bits of that byte are guaranteed to be zero. All other bits no assumptions can be made.

Comment: Summary: the upper 32 bits of 64-bit integer regs can hold garbage for 32-bit and narrower args.   It *is* different for args even narrower than 32, see the linked duplicate.